# Set cookie in mod Remodal When the window closes and reappears anymore

Tags: javascript

I'm using the [Remodal - modal Window](https://github.com/VodkaBears/Remodal/issues/) script, but How can I configure when that window closes it doesnot appear anymore for the visitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the event given in documentation and set some cookie, before showing modal to the user check that cookie

```
$(document).on('closed', '.remodal', function (e) {
    console.log('closed');
    // set cookie here
    console.log(e.reason);
});
```

Comment: Prepare some demo on jsfiddle or somewhere, try to solve problem yourself and show us what blocks you, don't expect someone will make the whole work for you- you won't learn anything this way

Answer (score 0):

Using [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) it would work something like this:

```
$(document).on('closed', '.remodal', function (e) {
    console.log('closed' + (e.reason ? ', reason: ' + e.reason : ''));
    Cookies.set('remodal_closed', '1', { expires: 7 });
});
```

Then check that the cookie doesn't exist before opening remodal:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if(!Cookies.get('remodal_closed')) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal().open();
    }, 3000); //set a more realistic time
  }
});
```

You might also need to set the cookie on confirmation:

```
$(document).on('confirmation', '.remodal', function () {
    console.log('confirmation');
    Cookies.set('remodal_closed', '1', { expires: 7 });
});
```